# About OnTriggerStay and Input.GetKeyDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

To go directly to the point, I'm having a bit of trouble with this code.
It seems that once I press the interactableKey ("E") and the InputGetKeyDown returns true, it stays true for about 6 executions of the OnTriggerStayMethod, they are not synchronized and so It breaks my code.

**Expected behavior:**
Player presses "E" when isHiding is false and statement 1 executes,and so  isHiding is set to true.
Player pressed "E" when isHiding is true and statement 2 executes, and so isHiding is set to false.

**Actual behavior:**
Player presses "E" when isHiding is false, statement 1 executes and sets isHiding to true and then immediately after this, statement 2 is also executed, because isHiding was set to true and apparently the return value for the Input.GetKeyDown is still true for a few OnTriggerStay execution frames. Which breaks my code.

This is the code:

```
 private void OnTriggerStay()
    {   
        //Statement 1
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(interactableKey) && this.isLocker && !PlayerManager.Instance.isHiding)
        {
            PlayerManager.Instance.currentHidingSpot = this.gameObject;
            PlayerManager.Instance.PerformHide();//This sets isHiding to true
            return; // This should be preventing the next if statement from being evaluated
        }
        //Statement 2
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(interactableKey) && this.isLocker && PlayerManager.Instance.isHiding)
        {
            PlayerManager.Instance.PerformExitHide(); //This sets isHiding to false
        }
    }
```

I am sorry if this is confusing, I don't usually ask questions here but I've never came across a problem quite like this one. Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnTriggerStay` method can be called multiple times per Unity Frame. It runs on the Physics clock cycle, instead of the Frame cycle. As such, you wouldn't use the `Input.GetKeyDown` here, because GetKeyDown is referencing the key down in the last frame.

Instead, try reading the input in the Update method, and then performing your actions in the OnTriggerStay method like this:

```
private bool allowInteraction;

private void Update ( )
{
    if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( interactableKey ) )
        allowInteraction = true;
}

private void OnTriggerStay ( )
{
    if ( allowInteraction && isLocker )
    {
        if ( PlayerManager.Instance.isHiding )
        {
            //Statement 2
            PlayerManager.Instance.PerformExitHide ( ); //This sets isHiding to false
        }
        else
        {
            //Statement 1
            PlayerManager.Instance.currentHidingSpot = this.gameObject;
            PlayerManager.Instance.PerformHide ( );//This sets isHiding to true
        }
    }
    allowInteraction = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, just a correction to your code, on Statement 1 we also gotta set allowInteraction = false otherwise it never gets reset due to the return.

Comment: @PedroCivaWiltuschnig you're right, I just copied and pasted your original code. I'll update the code.

Comment: `can be called multiple times per Unity frame` yes, but how it is phrased for me it sounds a bit misleading this way ;) I would rather say it like the API does: `OnTriggerStay is called once per physics update for every Collider other that is touching the trigger.` which helps to understand the **why** it might be called multiple times within one frame but still makes sure that this happens only in the physics updates and is not to be understood as something that happens multiple times on a `per frame` basis ;)