# How can I make this pick-up code work properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have  this script here that I took from a youtube tutorial. It only works sometimes in game and I don`t understand why.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : Interactable
{
    public GameObject FlashLightOnPlayer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        FlashLightOnPlayer.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    
   private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
   { 
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        FlashLightOnPlayer.SetActive(true);
        }
   }
  }
}
```

These are the two objects that I have. Flashlight(1) is a child of Player.

[Flashlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCdFU.png)
[Flashlight(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1emw.png)

I tried following this tutorial here : https://youtu.be/zEfahR66Pa8
Sometimes when I try and pick it up, it works, sometimes it doesn`t.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html:

> OnTriggerStay is called on ***almost*** all the frames for every Collider other that is touching the trigger. The function is on the physics timer so it won't necessarily run every frame.

With `Input.GetKey()`, you want to call it every frame in an `Update()` to not miss any key press. Calling `Input.GetKey()` inside something physic-based like `OnTriggerStay()` is risky as `OnTriggerStay()` run on an independent physic framerate. I've tried to find if there is anyone who use `Input.GetKey()` outside `Update()`, but so far I've found none. Your best bet is:

1. [Creating a flag in `OnTriggerStay()` and use `Update()` to check that flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44684696/14983586), or
2. [Creating a flag in `Update()` and use `OnTriggerStay()` to check that flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64407930/14983586).